# google.maps.Map() used but no data loaded, does that incur charges?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

## 1. SETUP

1. A trade show website uses the Google Maps JS API to display
   exhibitor locations as pins on a custom floor plan.
2. Pin locations are saved into the website's database only.
3. Google map data (maps, terrain, satellite etc) directions, street
   view and other functions are not used (just pan/zoom and pins).
4. The only resource loaded from Google is the JS API file (no maps, directions, other data etc).

---

## 2. QUESTIONS

Based on the docs, we use `google.maps.Map()` which incurs charges but the docs seem to assume `google.maps.Map()` will load data which we don't. We only load the the API JS file.

**1 - Will the maps be classified as a basic embed or be charged?**

**2 - If charged, how will they be classified so we can use the calculator?**
https://mapsplatformtransition.withgoogle.com/calculator

e.g. Embed advanced, Dynamic map etc?

**3 - Are the charges per API key, or per account (with multiple keys)?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maps JavaScript API is charged on map view basis. Each time you create new instance of Map or StreetView it will charge it. Zoom/pan isn't charged, tile imagery isn't charged. If you don't use services like geocoding and directions, the only source of billing are map views. Estimate how many map views has your project and use calculator to estimate costs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, question was updated. There seem to be different rates depending on the type though. We use the class which incurs a charge but don’t load any data from Google (no map, directions, street view etc). Does anyone know how to ask Google? The instructions for opening a ticket don’t work for us and there’s no phone for our country sorry.

Comment: whilst not a direct answer to your question what you can do is to create a static image representation of the map( presumably showing where your business is located ) and have that image be clickable - when clicked it will actually load the real map allowing users to interact with it. This should save casual "drive-by" charges... just a thought though

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks for the reply but our site generates 100s of maps (for each exhibitor) plus interactive sorting, and saves favourite pins. We need to give costs to the client but the docs are deeply confusing to us on this point sorry. 

We also tried opening a ticket but the instructions don't marry up with what we see half way through. And now the Stackoverflow gods have decided this question deserves to be closed so its a race against time. 

I'm sure someone knows so hopefully they can give a definitive answer, thanks for your help though, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
'Embed Advanced' maps don't use the JS API at all.

2.
A 'Dynamic Map' covers all JS API maps created with `google.maps.Map()` including maps which don't load Google map data in any way i.e. maps which load custom images (like a floor plan) as maps from other sources.